# Error updating Shape.area and Shape.length

Tags: arcobjects, .net

I am building a webservice with ArcObjects in C# .Net to insert a new feature or update an existing feature to a SDE-table. I am using the `IFeatureCursor` and an `IFeatureBuffer` to insert the features. When the geometry field ("Shape") is set, an COMException is thrown saying:

```
"Unable to update area or length field in response to shape update"
```

Obviously, this refers to the default feature class fields `Shape.area` and `Shape.length` that are calculated automatically. I have also tried to insert features using the `CreateFeature()` and `feature.Store()` method, but this resulted in the same exception.

Just to be clear, this happens before I call the `cursor.InsertFeature(featureBuffer)` or `cursor.UpdateFeature(feature)` method.

My code looks like this:

```
private void Create(Result result)
    {
        var featureClassLoad = (IFeatureClassLoad) _master;
        var schemaLock = (ISchemaLock) _master;
        IFeatureCursor cursor = null;
        IFeatureBuffer featureBuffer = null;

        try
        {
            schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);
            featureClassLoad.LoadOnlyMode = true;
            cursor = _master.Insert(false);
            featureBuffer = _master.CreateFeatureBuffer();

            foreach (var attr in result.Attributes)
            {
                var attributeName = attr.Field.Name;
                var index = _master.FindField(attributeName);
                if (attributeName == _master.ShapeFieldName)
                {
                    featureBuffer.Value[index] = attr.NewGeometry;//Exception thrown
                    continue;
                }

                if (attributeName == "ID")
                {
                    featureBuffer.Value[index] = "{" + result.Guid.ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
                    continue;
                }
                featureBuffer.Value[index] = attr.NewValue;
            }
            cursor.InsertFeature(featureBuffer);
            cursor.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (featureBuffer != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(featureBuffer);
            if (cursor != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cursor);
            featureClassLoad.LoadOnlyMode = false;
            schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: Are you trying to update a column, or the read-only property of the geometry?

Comment: The exception occurs whenever I set the shapefield of the IFeatureBuffer. So if I understand you question correctly, I am trying to update a the geometry column.

Comment: You can update the geometry coordinates, but not the area or length properties.  Once the coordinates are changed, the area and length values are changed accordingly.

Comment: Well, that is the problem. I update the geometry coordinates. At the moment this is executed in code arcobjects uses these coordinates to fill the Shape.area and Shape.Length automatically. That is when something goes wrong. I don't update these area and length fields myself...

Comment: It looks like your logic could be trying to update the area/length pseudo-columns.  What is the complete column list generated by result.Attributes?

Comment: Personally I would not have set the geometry in the manner you have, not sure it makes a difference but try featureBuffer.Shape = attr.newGeometry?

Comment: @Vince, I understand what you're saying, but the Attributes List is not being generated in a loop, so I made certain it is not updating those area/length columns. As a matter of fact, when I comment out this line:
featureBuffer.Value[index] = attr.NewGeometry;
the feature is being inserted with null geometry.

Comment: @Hornbydd: I've tried that as well, with the same result though

Comment: Is the geometry valid?  Both with respect to itself and with respect to the supported geometries in the feature class?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. I also created a dummygeometry right before it gets inserted to the _master feature class. Same result... I've already spent days trying all kinds of things. But really, thanks a lot for thinking with me! Keep shooting, I'd say... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire flow of my code was executed within one servercontext. I suppose therefore some references to the table were not released sufficiently however I always released the FeatureCursors and Workspaces when not longer needed.

I solved my problem by creating and releasing different servercontexts for different parts of my code. Existing references are released more thoroughly now.